# Using a parameter for expression function

Tags: r, legend

I'm trying to plot a figure legend which I create with the `expression` function, where the argument to `expression` is a character which I want to plot as Greek letter symbol.

Here's an example of what I tried which obviously doesn't work:

```
param = "tau"
tau.vec = c(1,2,3,4)
plot(tau.vec, tau.vec)
legend("bottomright", sapply(tau.vec, function(x) expression(paste(param, "=", x, sep = " "))))
```

Any idea how should I do it?

Comment: Change `expression` to `as.expression`.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either

Comment: By "works", you mean it actually replaces `x` with 1,2,3 and 4? Or is it just a legend with `param=x` 4 times?

Comment: -1 It works for me. It lists `tau = 1` on the first line `tau = 2` on the second line and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
param = as.symbol("tau")
tau.vec = c(1,2,3,4)
plot(tau.vec, tau.vec)
legend("bottomright",as.expression(sapply(tau.vec, 
    function(x) bquote(.(param)==.(x)))))
```

`expression()` doesn't allow for escaping with variable values, `bquote()` does with the `.()` syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately this creates "param = 1", "param = 2", ... instead of replacing param with the Greek tau symbol.

Comment: Oh I see, `param` was another variable. I just changed it to a symbol and escaped it as well

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Any idea how would this solution work if my param = "p(tau)". So I would the legend to be "p(Greek.tau) = 1", p(Greek.tau) = 2", ... ?

Comment: It would be easiest to define `param = quote(p(tau))`